# What is the limit of x and y?

Tags: limits

In a question, a limit is given as :

$$0<X<Y<1$$

what's is the limit of x and y??

Is it: $0<X<Y$ and $X<Y<1$ ?

Or, $0<X<1$ and $X<Y<1$ ?

Comment: If that is given as a limit, there is a typo or other miscommunication. That is not a limit.

Comment: As stated this doesn't make any sense. Can you provide more context?

Comment: maybe you are asking for the _range_ of values $X$ and $Y$ can take?

Comment: @DS yeah actually it is.

Comment: $x$ can take any value in the range $0 < x < 1.$  Also, $y$ can take any value in the range $0 < y < 1.$  These ranges, while accurate, are given without any consideration that $x$ must be less than $y$.  It would also be accurate to say that $0 < x < 1$ **and** $x < y < 1.$

Comment: You say “in a question”. If you edit your post to include that whole question, maybe someone can make sense of what you mean...